# how to import variable from javasvript to html script tag

Tags: javascript, import, django-templates

I'm making webpage with django templete. In the HTML script tag, I make a variable which contains geojson data, so that it is too long to be contained in a single file.(about 10000 lines) So I want to detach it another place. var "areas" in the image is it.

[image]

So I want to detach that variable to another file(maybe .js file? any format no matter.)

1. Where I should save that variable? is it .js file?
2. How can I import that variable in HTML script tag?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Use A JS File with just the variable and importing it through script tag would work fine. Like if it was saved in `areas.js` use the code
`<script src = "areas.js"></script>`
in the body tag then you can just the use variable like normal in scripts

Comment: sorry, It does not seem to solve my problem. 
areas.js and mainpage.html are in same directory.
areas.js : var a=3;
mainpage.html : <script src="areas.js>console.log(a);</script>
error message: Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/areas.js/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. / So, I edited mainpage.html : <script type="application/js" src="areas.js>console.log(a);</script> and this does not work.

Comment: The Script Tag Should Be Empty not having any other console log things. Like in mainpage.html inside body tag add the code given above(Copy And Paste). Then If You want to add more scripts add Another script tag and use the functions wanted.

Comment: The Updated Code Should Be   `<script src = "areas.js"></script><script>console.log(a)</script>`

Comment: In that way, I got "a is not defined" in console... I can;t understand why..

Comment: replace a with the variable you assigned for the variable i guess `areas` as in the screenshot you have given

Answer (score 1):

You can put that data in a `.json` file on your server.
Than do something like following to fetch the json and parse it.

```js
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
     // Use data in your app.
  });
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

You can also use async/await to avoid the .then and callback.

```js
async function fetchMoviesJSON() {
  const response = await fetch('/movies.json');
  const movies = await response.json();
  // Use the data in your app.
}
fetchMoviesJSON();
```

Comment: OP here wants to use the data in his personal project and not just display it on the Console.

Comment: @mrtechtroid That logic can be written within the .then() as per their need.

Comment: I Know That, In The Main Question Asks How He Can Import It As a Variable Rather Than Console Log It.

Comment: @mrtechtroid changed my answer to have a comment instead of console.log.